# How can I can show a div if an object doesn't have a value outside of the object scope

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a small Nuxt issue that I can't work out how to get around.

Essentially, I have an object (used for a carousel slider).

```html
<template>
  <div
    :class="[$style.swiperSlide, 'swiper-slide']"
    v-for="slide in slides"
    :key="slide.id">
    <nuxt-img
      :class="[$style.img]"
      :alt="slide.alt"
      :src="imgSources(slide)"
      sizes="sm:100vw"
    />
    <div :class="[$style.info, 'info-b']" v-if="slide.info">
      {{ slide.info }} 
    </div>
  </div>

  <button :class="[$style.infoOpen]" 
    @click="showTab" 
    v-if="slideInfoAvailable"
  >
    Close
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    slides: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
      default: () => []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    slideInfoAvailable() {
      return this.slide?.info
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
      . . .
    });
  },
  methods: {
    imgSources(slide) {
      return `/img${slide.imgPath}.jpg`;
    },
};
</script>
```

All works o.k, the problem is that I have a button outside of this `v-for` that I need to only be visible if there's `slide.info` but because this div is outside of the `v-for` it can't tell if it's available.

> Cannot read property 'info' of undefined

The easiest way out of this is to add the button inside of the slider - but I can't for Z-index CSS issues. It has to be outside of the 'slider' div.

Any ideas how I can only show the button if there's `slide.info`? For some of my slides, there won't be.

```html
<slider
  :slides="[
    {
      imgPath: '/demo',
      info: 'Demo info for this slide',
      alt: 'Homepage'
    },
     {
      imgPath: '/demo2',
      alt: 'Homepage'
    },
  ]"
/>
```

One way I could do it would be to see if `.slide-active .style.info` exists. If it doesn't exist then I can hide the button as `slide-active` is added to the active div by the slider API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is coming from the fact that you probably have some async fetching and that `slides` are not available upon initial render. To prevent this, you can use a `computed` with some [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) like this

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    slideInfoAvailable() {
      return this.slide?.info
    }
  }
}
```

Then, call it like this

```html
<button :class="[$style.infoOpen]" @click="showTab" v-if="slideInfoAvailable">
```

You cannot use `?.` directly in the `template`.

You could also do the classic way of

```html
<button :class="[$style.infoOpen]" @click="showTab" v-if="slide && slide.info">
```

but it does not look as sexy IMO (but you do not need any `computed`).

And yeah, for this kind of thing, better to handle it with Vue than relying on some hacky dirty CSS tricks!

Comment: Thanks, I can see what this is trying to do but for some reason the button is now hidden from all slides, even if there is slide.info? slideInfoAvailable is undefined.

Comment: @cmp maybe try `this.slide?.info?.length`. If it still does not work, it is coming from the way you're fetching your slides maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your continued support. Still undefined, however. I can see what this is trying to do but I can't work out why it's undefined and hidden across all slides. Most odd :( I have added to my original if it is any good to you?

Comment: Use your vue devtools and check also in the network tab. It was working before, right? Must be something trivial.